# Phonegap android application cpu usage in background

Tags: android, cordova, webview, cpu-usage

I have been doing a phonegap app for android but am stuck on the following; When I background the app and check the task magager, the app still consumes a considerable amount of CPU (between 5% and sometimes even to 15%). I have tried removing all other parts of my code but the only thing that stops the app from having CPU activity in the background is removing the phonegap.js from my code.

I was under the impression that Phonegap would halt javascript execution when going into onPause but I must be missing something.

I have tried 1.1.0, 1.2.0 & 1.3.0 to no avail. Interesting too is that if I fire up 2 apps with phonegap, their background CPU usage seem to behave the same: One goes up, the other goes up and mostly they are exact in usage up to the percentage point.

Has anyone got any idea what the app is still doing in CPU and/or how I could find out ?

Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the js execution is not halted when the app goes into onPause, it only halts when the app is closed/killed.

Comment: Is there a change to "pause" the webbrowser control, that is used by PhoneGap?

Answer (score 1):

Cordova/PhoneGaps default behaivior is to keep the app running in background, you can change that by adding a "keepRunning" tag to your config.xml:

**keepRunning (boolean, defaults to true)** - 
*Determines whether Cordova will keep running in the background or not*

```
<preference name="keeprunning" value="false"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I noticed the same problem, especially on KitKat.  To resolve the issue, in your main activity (the activity which extends DroidGap), you need to call the onPause() method for your WebView (which is the 'appView' variable).

This pauses any extra processing associated with the WebView which should reduce your CPU usage significantly:

```
@Override
protected void onPause()
{
    super.onPause();

    if (appView != null)
    {
        appView.onPause();
    }
}

@Override
protected void onResume()
{
    super.onResume();

    if (appView != null)
    {
        appView.onResume();
    }
}
```